# Filter by multiple categories

Tags: categories, filter

I need to filter a sections entries by more than one category but only return entries that belong to all category id's passed in a URL parameter.

Now I can get the correct output if the id's are hard coded but not if contained in the URL parameter.

URL: ajax-swatches?cats=171,172,179

{% set catPars = craft.request.getParam('cats') %}

{% set swatches = craft.entries({
    section: 'swatches',
    relatedTo: ['and',catPars]
}) %}

I presume the 'relatedTo' section is treating the 'catPars' variable as a single entry and ignoring the ',' and next values?

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Craft's [relatedTo](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) takes a model, an ID, or an array of either of these. So if you're passing `'171,172,179'` It's probably coming through as a string and only reading the first ID.

Try making it an array and looping through the values:

```
{% set catPars = craft.request.getParam('cats')|split(',') %}
{% set related = ['and'] %}
{% for catPar in catPars %}
    {% set related = related|merge([{targetElement: catPar}]) %}
{% endfor %}


{% set swatches = craft.entries({ section: 'swatches', relatedTo: related }) %}
```

Without knowing your setup I don't know if it's actually `targetElement` or `sourceElement`. You can also pass in the `field` name as well if you want to get more specific. See the documentation linked above for the definitions of all of those.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for the reply. I have tried a range of methods using the guidelines but none seem to help. When I try your method I get no entries at all :(

Comment: You're right, that was incorrect -- I updated it with a better answer.

Comment: Hi Peter, I actually used your first answer to do exactly this. However 'catPar' fails to add to the array so we end up with one array entry of 'and'....

Comment: Can you edit your original question and post your code? I've tested that exact code and it works fine for me.

Comment: It could be that you need extra square brackets around the hash to merge, so it's `merge([{ targetElement: catPar }])`.

Comment: @carlcs is right! Typo here that wasn't in my test. Thanks carlcs, updated!

Comment: And you should prevent to pass an array with `'and'` only. So a conditional with `{% if related|length > 1 %}` should be added.

Comment: Thanks guys that's perfect. It now works perfectly. I will add a condition so that 'and' only get added if required. My Twig syntax knowledge needs some work, so I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: @TheSwebSite you could do it like this: `{% set related = (related|length > 1) ?: '' %}`. This before `{% set swatches = ... %}` and you should always have a correct `relatedTo` argument, even if no category is passed. It should returns all "swatches" entries then.