# GET Checkbox Value to the Query (Entries Field)

Tags: entries, filter, query, entries-field

I am writing my first post because I am stuck and cannot move forward. I need a filter that filters by "Entries Field." The selection is done through a form + checkbox. I also get the ID of the entries through the selection. But passing it on is simply not working.

For example, now the Checkbox with ID 364 & 366 is selected.

```
{%- for i in 1..loopLength -%}

            {%- if craft.app.request.getParam('traffic[opt_2_'~ i ~']') is not empty -%}
            
                    {%- set i_value = '"'~ craft.app.request.getParam('traffic[opt_2_'~ i ~']') ~'"' -%}
                    {%- set traffic = traffic|merge([i_value]) -%}

            {%- endif -%}
            
    {%- endfor -%}
```

```
{%- set filter = traffic|join(',') -%}
 => OUTPUT: 364, 366
```

My Query:

```
{% set output = craft.entries()
    .filter(['and', filter])    
        .all() 
%}
```

** OUTPUT: NO Results **

But when I manually enter the ID, the query works.

```
{% set output = craft.entries()
    .filter(['and', 364, 366])    
    .all() 
%}
```

Output: 3 Results (in my Example)

Otherwise, I don't know how to pass the selected checkboxes and their ID's.

Comment: this is the answer to my question:

https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9200/filter-by-multiple-categories?rq=1

Comment: Glad you found an answer. I think you may want to mark this primary question as answered as well.